# Excel macro execution error in VN.Net code

Tags: excel, vb.net

In a vb.net application, I call an Excel object in which I run a macro.
Everything works, but when my application takes over, it crashes with this error message.

> System.InvalidOperationException
> HResult=0x80131509
> Message=Impossible de résoudre toutes les références de propriété dans le chemin de la propriété 'LayoutTransform.ScaleX'. Vérifiez que les objets applicables prennent en charge les propriétés.
> Source=PresentationFramework

translated:

> System.InvalidOperationException HResult=0x80131509 Message=Unable to resolve all property references in the path of the 'LayoutTransform.ScaleX' property. Verify that the applicable objects support the properties. Source=PresentationFramework

```
Public Sub RunMacroNomOrdo()
    Dim oExcel As New Excel.Application
    Dim oBook As Excel.Workbook
    oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(_nFicNomOrdo)
    oExcel.Visible = True
    Try
        oExcel.Run("NomOrdo", _nFicNomCatia, _nFicAttribs)
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: On what line does the error occur? `oExcel.Run`?

Comment: yes, the error occurs on the oExcel.run line but after the macro is executed in Excel.

Comment: The error is basically saying it doesn't have a reference. I don't see `_nFicNomCatia, _nFicAttribs` defined anywhere; are they? They should accept the data types Excel wants to put in them. Do you know where `LayoutTransform.ScaleX` is being referenced?

Comment: the variables _nFicNomCatia and _nFicAttribs are defined.
the error appears when the Excel file is opened from a server. If the file is copied locally on the PC, there is no more error message.

Comment: Maybe something needs to be installed on the server, relating to `LayoutTransform.Scalex`?

Comment: The error appears again.I have this in debugger
.. : Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework-SystemCore\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\PresentationFramework-SystemCore.dll'. 
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'ScaleX' property not found on 'object' ''MatrixTransform' (HashCode=62329248)'. null
.
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Unable to resolve all property references in the 'LayoutTransform.ScaleX' property path. Check that the applicable objects support the properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I open and run the macro in a BackgroundWorker. This solves the problem.